# How to use LINQ to separate column entry and count

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Sample DataTable (`UseDate` column):

```
Jun 2 2015 1:55PM
Jun 2 2015 2:05PM
Jul 3 2016 1:12PM
Jul 4 2016 2:43AM
```

I am trying to use LINQ to do so it is the fastest (as the record will go way over thousands and more).

I have the following so far:

```
var dateAdded = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<String>("UseDate"))
    .Select(grp => new { Date = grp.Key.ToString().Substring(0, grp.Key.LastIndexOf(' ')).Trim(), Count = grp.Key.ToString().Substring(0, grp.Key.LastIndexOf(' ')).Count() });
```

I am getting the following:

```
Date = "Jun 2 2015", Count = 6
Date = "Jun 2 2015", Count = 6
Date = "Jul 3 2016", Count = 4
Date = "Jul 4 2016", Count = 4
```

I am not sure how the count is being done either.

I would like to know the count of each date (e.g. `Jun 2 2015`) from the DataTable above.

So above would tell me:

```
Date = "Jun 2 2015", Count = 2
Date = "Jul 3 2016", Count = 1
Date = "Jul 4 2016", Count = 1
```

Comment: Seems like you want `Count = grp.Count()`.  Right now you're counting characters in a string, though it doesn't match up with your results.  Also you need to group on the truncated date.

Comment: Is the dataTable linked to database or inmemory?

Comment: @juharr I don't have to touch the `.Count()` method as it will count anything in the `Data` section?

Comment: When you do a `GroupBy` the result is a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TResult>>`  Each `IGrouping` has a `Key` and is a `IEnumerable<TResult>` meaning you can use Linq methods on it like `Count` that will only apply to the rows that match the key you selected.

Comment: @juharr Thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you need to group on the truncated date, so select the column, then truncate it.  Then you can get the count of each grouping.

```
var dateAdded = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row.Field<String>("UseDate"))
    .Select(fullDate => fullDate.Substring(0, fullDate.LastIndexOf(' ')).Trim())
    .GroupBy(truncatedDate => truncatedDate)
    .Select(grp => new 
    { 
        Date = grp.Key,
        Count = grp.Count() 
    });
```

Comment: Although this works is the `truncatedDate` taken by from `Select`? I was almost close :). I didn't realize the `Count` doesn't need to be truncated at all. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I did the multiple selects to avoid something like `GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("UseDate").Substring(0, row.Field<string>("UseDate").LastIndexOf(' ')).Trim())`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `DateTime` format in the database is always like you've mentioned, you can use this to `GroupBy` correctly. It parses to datetime first and groups by just the `Date` part.

```
var dateAdded = dataTable.AsEnumerable()  
    .GroupBy(row => DateTime.ParseExact(row.Field<String>("UseDate"), 
          "MMM d yyyy h:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date);
```